# Pruning a powerset based on a graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, sets

I have a list of nodes `l = [1, 2, 3, ... , n]` and a list of tuples `p = [(1, 2), (2, 3), ...]`, where the latter represents which pairs of nodes have an edge between them.

I would like to write a function that takes the above as input and returns a subset of the powerset of `l` where each set has nodes which construct a complete graph based on `p` (sans the empty set).

For example, suppose I have `l = [1, 2, 3]` and `p = [(1, 2), (2, 3)]`. Then the output of this function would be `[(1), (2), (3), (1, 2), (2, 3)]`.

What would be the most efficient way of implementing this function?

Comment: Presumably you have additional constraints (such as wanting the maximum-size subset of the powerset of $l$), since if any nonempty subset will do, then just a single node of $l$ that is mentioned somewhere in $p$ suffices.

Comment: If you don't want simply a single largest subset of $l$ with this property, then the thing you probably want is the set of all such subsets that are inclusionwise maximal.  This is the set of maximal (not maximum) cliques, and can be found using the [Bron-Kerbosch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm).  Note that this could generate $3^{n/3}$ such subsets, so no poly-time algorithm is possible.  (This is still better than listing *all* such subsets, of which there could be as many as $2^n$.)